# Match or Return the columns that have the same date as a specified column in R

Tags: r

I am working with a large set of patient data.  The patients each have a row and all the different tests are marked as dates in that row with column names such as Test 1, Test 2, etc..  If I want to see which other tests have the same date as Test 1 for each patient, what is the best way to code that query?  There may be one match, there may be many, there may be none.  I want to be able to see, for each patient, which tests were done on the same day as Test 1.  So this is probably a match problem, but for more than the first match.

```
id<-c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4")
test1<-c("04-04-2004","05-05-2005","06-06-2006", "07-07-2007")
test2<-c("04-04-2005","05-05-2005","06-06-2007","07-07-2007")
test3<-c("04-04-2008","05-05-2005","06-06-2008","07-07-2007")
test4<-c("04-04-2005","05-05-2005","06-06-2009", "07-07-2008")
df<-data.frame(id,test1,test2,test3,test4)
```

I want the data to return to me the matches for test1, for example: for ID1: test4; for ID2: test2,test3,test4; for ID3: - ; for ID4: test2,test3.

Comment: Thanks, Ronak Shah, I edited it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach. Dates are converted to `Date` format (note that you were missing quotes around the dates, and probably `c()` to combine the strings as well). You can `pivot_longer` to put data into long format, one date per row. Then grouping by `id`, you can compare dates with the date of test1, and `filter` (keep) those. The `complete` will fill in missing `id` where there are no matches.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("test"), as.Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = "test", values_to = "date") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(date == date[test == "test1"] & test != "test1") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(id = df$id) %>%
  select(-date)
```

**Output**

```
  id    test 
  <chr> <chr>
1 ID1   NA   
2 ID2   test2
3 ID2   test3
4 ID2   test4
5 ID3   NA   
6 ID4   test2
7 ID4   test3
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"), test1 = c("04-04-2004", 
"05-05-2005", "06-06-2006", "07-07-2007"), test2 = c("04-04-2005", 
"05-05-2005", "06-06-2007", "07-07-2007"), test3 = c("04-04-2008", 
"05-05-2005", "06-06-2008", "07-07-2007"), test4 = c("04-04-2005", 
"05-05-2005", "06-06-2009", "07-07-2008")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```